# javascript loop array and object data in one table

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have array and object data i want to call those together.

```
var data = [
{"number": "PA1234","name": "John"},
{"number": "JM344","name": "jessi"},
{"number": "ML567","name": "Monty"}
];

var costing= {
"cost": 10,
"cost": 20,
"cost": 30,
};
```

Display Format in table

```
<pre>
<table>
<tr>
<td>number</td>
<td>name</td>
<td>cost</td>
</tr>
</table>
<pre>
```

I have done so far but don't know how to called the object costing

```
var records=$("<table/>").attr("id","tabs");
$("#table").append(records);
for(var j=0;j<data .length;j++)
{
  var tr="<tr>";
  var td1="<td>"+data [j]["number"]+"</td>";
  var td2="<td>"+data [j]["name"]+"</td>";

  $("#tabs").append(tr+td1+td2+td3); 
}
```

Comment: Did you make any efforts before to achieve that?

Comment: Try something. SO isn't a free code-writing service.

Comment: Your `costing` variable is not an array and so the data is wrong. You only have one `cost` in there.

Comment: the object for `costing` uses the the same  key for multiple attributes. That is not possible in JS. It's just like writing: `var costing= {"cost": 30};`

Comment: @Utkanos I agree with you. This is an [off-topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)!

Comment: Since the data is wrong you can't expect to get a decent result out of it. Anyway here is something that can get you started: https://jsfiddle.net/cyt1fr23/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>

        </title>
        <style>
            #t, tr, th, td{
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="t" cellpadding="10">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Number
                </th>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Cost
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    <script>
        var number = ['PA1234', 'JM344', 'ML567'], name = ['John', 'Jessi', 'Monty'], costing = [30, 30, 30];
        for(var i=0;i<3;i++) {
            $("#t").append('<tr><td>' + number[i] + '</td><td>' + name[i] + '</td><td>' + costing[i] + '</td></tr>');
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

This is what you want

Answer (score 1):

Had to change some things with your second object, costing. I don't think you can have the same key names on different values, you wouldn't be able to iterate over them. Now you can do two approaches:

```
 var data = [
    {"number": "PA1234","name": "John"},
    {"number": "JM344","name": "jessi"},
    {"number": "ML567","name": "Monty"}
];

var costing = {
"cost0": 10,
"cost1": 20,
"cost2": 30,
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

    const place = document.getElementById("place").firstElementChild
    const table = document.createElement("table")

    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        let tr = document.createElement("tr")

        let tdNumber = document.createElement("td")
        let tdName = document.createElement("td")
        let tdCost = document.createElement("td")

        tdNumber.innerText = data[i].number
        tdName.innerText = data[i].name
        tdCost.innerText = costing["cost"+i]

        tr.appendChild(tdNumber)
        tr.appendChild(tdName)
        tr.appendChild(tdCost)

        table.appendChild(tr)


    } 

    place.appendChild(table)

})
```

However personally i would change your costing object to this:

```
 var costing2 = [
    10,20,30
]
```

And change the for loop to this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    let tr = document.createElement("tr")

    let tdNumber = document.createElement("td")
    let tdName = document.createElement("td")
    let tdCost = document.createElement("td")

    tdNumber.innerText = data[i].number
    tdName.innerText = data[i].name
    tdCost.innerText = costing2[i]

    tr.appendChild(tdNumber)
    tr.appendChild(tdName)
    tr.appendChild(tdCost)

    table.appendChild(tr)


}
```

Where place is the spot of the div tag in the html. Not the best solution but it works, putting down the html code aswell if you want that:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="./file.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="place">
            <pre>

            </pre>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```